# error al cambiar valor de input traido con include php usando jquery javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

en mi primer archivo index tengo el codigo que al presionar boton cambia el valor de un input, lo presiono pero no me asigna a mi input el valor que quiero asignarle , he probrado con 2 formas , con jquery y javascript

window.addEventListener("load", cargaPagina);
function cargaPagina() {
var btn = document.getElementById("boton1").addEventListener("click", cambiaValores);
   }

primera

```
function cambiaValores() {
  console.log('boton');
  $("#respuesta").prop('value', 'Save');
  $('#respuesta').val("10");
}
```

segunda

```
function cambiaValores() {
 var inputNombre = document.getElementById("respuesta");
        inputNombre.value = "400";
  }
```

el input me lo traigo con un include php

```
<th>Respuesta:</th><td><input name="respuesta" id="respuesta" placeholder="Ingrese su Respuesta" required></td>
```

Obtengo un console log cuando lo inserto en la validacion de click de mi boton pero no me asigna el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi boton html generado con php

```
 $verificarnumero = "<a id=\"boton1\" ><button id=\"boton1\" title=\"no procede\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn especial  orange darken-1 hvr-pulse\"><i class=\"fa fa-exclamation\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></button></a>";
```

Comment: `$('#respuesta').val('10')` funciona, pero en tu código estás usando `$('.respuesta')`

Comment: probe las 2 con el id, copie mal el codigo, ya voy a subir como tengo el boton @DavidSilva

Comment: Añade esto en el evento y dinos que dice la consola: `console.log(document.querySelector('#respuesta'))`

Comment: esto es lo que muestra 
<input type="hidden" id="respuesta" value="DYP">
@FranciscoGarrido

Comment: Me he fijado que en la declaración del input no le asignas ningún tipo, ha de ser tipo hidden? y de ser asi, pon otra vez el codigo al final del cambio de valor y ver si asi cambia el value

Comment: ya le asigne un tipo text pero no me funciona.
sigue sin funcionar

Comment: ya vi cual era el error, tenia otro campo con el mismo id, el mismo tenia el atributo hidden @FranciscoGarrido gracias